# what is the problem of this code in c++

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T tVar;
    public:
    Foo(T t):tVar() {}
};

class FooDerived: public Foo<std::string> {};

FooDerived fd;
```

what is the problem of this code?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget the compiler output?

Comment: The output of the compiler. You know, when you try to build it?

Comment: @ratzip: He means that OP didn't post any compiler error. It's hard to know what's wrong this way.

Answer (score 7):

the problem is Foo does not have an empty C'tor - Foo(void), while FooDerived is trying to initialize the Foo with an empty C'tor (since it is the default..) so you will get a compilation error, since the compiler does not know how to create DerivedFoo()

Comment: that's right, and in addition the provided c'tor `Foo(T t):tVar() {}` is actually a default c'tor as is does not make any use of the `t` parameter, so it can be omitted altogether (or changed to `Foo(T t):tVar(t) {}`)